# What is a better method to suspend program execution until a condition is met?

Tags: delphi

I need to wait until a mapped network folder (\HostName\NetworkPath) become empty. What I mean is that program flow cannot continue until that network folder is empty.

So far I have the following logic in place  but I noticed that it takes time before FindFirst notices that the network folder become empty.

If I keep observing an opened explorer windows, pointing to that network folder, I notice that it become empty *far before* FindFirst notices it.

I used Sleep(5000) to introduce some delay in calling again CheckNetworkFolderIsEmpty in my while loop, otherwise it is being called too often. But maybe that folder will become empty far before 5 seconds, so 5 seconds is an arbitrary time delay that may results in an unnecessary dealy in program execution, in the event that the folder become empty before.

What can be the culprit, what can be a better alternative?

Also I do not know what else to use instead of a simple Sleep.

```pascal
while not CheckRawFolderIsEmpty do begin
    Sleep(5000);
end;
```

```pascal
function TForm1.CheckNetworkFolderIsEmpty: Boolean;
begin
    Result := (CountFilesInFolder('\\HostName\NetworkPath', '*.txt') = 0);
end;

function CountFilesInFolder(const aPath, aFileMask: string): Integer;
var
    Path: string;
    SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
    Path := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(aPath);
    Result := 0;
    if FindFirst(Path + aFileMask, faAnyFile and not faDirectory, SearchRec) = 0 then begin
        repeat
            Inc(Result);
        until FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0;
        FindClose(SearchRec);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I am not sure about Delphi, but in general: a sleep isnt that bad for such purposes.

Comment: What version of Delphi?

Comment: In any case, why not use [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationw) and just wait for the OS to tell you when the directory's contents change?

Comment: The version is Delphi Berlin

Comment: Note that doing a full count just to check for emptiness is overkill. Exit the function as soon as 1 file is found. And you need better error handling of `Find(First|Next)()` to avoid your code assuming empitness if a real error occurs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observing file system changes like you do is inefficient (`FindFirst`, `FindNext`) and inacurate as you've learned. Windows provides API [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationw) for that purpose as [J...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493264/what-is-a-better-method-to-suspend-program-execution-until-a-condition-is-met#comment99576880_56493264) has pointed out in the comment under your question.

Good news is that you don't need to start studying the API from scratch, because some other people did the hard work for you. Check out some freeware wrappers for Delphi around the API:

- https://torry.net/pages.php?id=252
- http://www.angusj.com/delphi/dirwatch.html
- ...

Comment: Thank you all, found an excellent example here: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/76318-monitor-a-folder-for-changes/

Comment: @FabioVitale The usage of FindFirstChangeNotificationW is simpler than [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) for the cost of less information provided. In case of deeper interest in topic be sure to check out [part 1](https://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html) and [part 2](https://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw_19.html) of Understanding ReadDirectoryChangesW by Jim Beveridge.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Wolf I will check out  part 1 and part 2 of Understanding ReadDirectoryChangesW by Jim Beveridge